# Xamarin Binding library fails to render

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've successfully bound the following Android library to Xamarin. But when I try to use it, the app crashes with an Unhandled Exception. Following is the output being printed.

[ChromeLikeTabSwitcher](https://github.com/michael-rapp/ChromeLikeTabSwitcher)

```
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): Process: App1.App1, PID: 16090
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): java.lang.IllegalStateException: No decorator has been set
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): at de.mrapp.android.util.Condition.throwException(Condition.java:60)
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): at de.mrapp.android.util.Condition.ensureNotNull(Condition.java:250)
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): at de.mrapp.android.tabswitcher.TabSwitcher$5.onGlobalLayout(TabSwitcher.java:655)
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): at de.mrapp.android.tabswitcher.layout.AbstractTabSwitcherLayout$LayoutListenerWrapper.onGlobalLayout(AbstractTabSwitcherLayout.java:112)
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnGlobalLayout(ViewTreeObserver.java:986)
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2210)
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1301)
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7016)
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
12-14 11:08:27.196 E/AndroidRuntime(16090): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
12-14 11:09:20.646 I/Process (16090): Sending signal. PID: 16090 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing the TabSwitcherDecorator. You need to implement a `TabSwitcherDecorator` subclass and set is via `TabSwitcher.SetDecorator`

Comment: You mean using Metadata.xml?

Comment: No, I mean create/implement  a `TabSwitcherDecorator` subclass, instance it and assign it to your `TabSwitcher` instance, that is in your implementation code, not in your binding library.